# Buring ISO File to USB

Tags: files, iso

I am getting ready to burn an ISO of the Ubuntu OS to a USB drive.  Where do I find and download the ISO file?  Do I need to download the entire OS, and if yes, does this impact my current Windows OS?  My goal is not to replace my current Windows OS but to use the bootable USB to get into a computer I inherited that has Win 8 and is password protected.  I was told that I could bypass the password if I booted with a Linux OS.  This is my last resort before simply ditching the computer.

Answer (score 0):

You're not looking for Ubuntu. There is a Linux distro which is designed to kick the password query out of the ram of Windows. However, since as a Windows user you don't know how to make a bootable device, it'd be easier just to use the protected mode / save mode (whatever it's called on Windows, everyone I know uses Windows in German, therefore I only know the German word for it) to replace the password with whatever you want to replace it with. If you boot in the protected mode / save mode, you can log into the admin account without password. Since you're new to this page: Please press the tick on the left it this solves your problem.

Comment: Hi...I can change the boot process so that the computer boots in safe mode but it still prompts me for the original password that was set by our deceased friend.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. So you don't want to lose the password but access the files on the computer?

Comment: I want to be able to bypass the password our friend created and get to the desktop and/or bypass his password and get to a screen where I can either disable it or create a new one.  I have gotten to a command prompt through one of the utility programs and it does not appear that he had been creating or saving files to this laptop.  I can see and open the directories and there are no saved files.

Comment: Just want to be able to use the computer...if there are files there, I will delete them since they are of no value to me.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your first comment. Booting into safe mode isn't enough. If you are there, log in as administrator. Then open this terminalish thing of Windows. Type in `net user [user name]  [some new password]`. Brackets are there to indicate variables, don't type in the brackets.

Comment: How do I get to screen that allows me to log in as administrator--assuming he did not set an admin password, too.  Our friend used to be an MIS prof in his day and was quite fastidious when it came to data security.

Comment: You'll see the login screen when booting into safe mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the information that you need @ http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows. These steps will not hurt your current windows system. You can download the iso file from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: Yes, and it still shows as his local account "Den-Den"

Comment: I went back to the trouble shooting utility and right clicked the cmd prompt..it shows that Den-Den is the only account and it said that this was the Admin account.